# Node url.format is deprecated, what should we use instead?

Tags: node.js

I am getting warnings in VS Code that [`url.format`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlformaturl-options) from the NodeJS URL module is deprecated.

```js
const nodeUrl = require('url')

const url = nodeUrl.format({
  protocol: 'https',
  host: 'example.com',
  pathname: 'somepath'
})
```

What shall I use instead? Is it fully safe to just replace the above by

```js
const buildUrl = (url) => url.protocol + '://' + url.host + '/' + url.pathname
```

Are these two functions equivalent, that is, for any object input with that structure, it results in the same output? Doesn't `url.format` have any magic that I may miss? For example `pathname` with or without leading `/`.

My project is huge with a lot of calls to `url.format` and I want to be sure that nothing breaks.

**edit**: Apparently we should use [WHATWG URL standard](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlformaturlobject)

Is then this the correct replacement?

```js
const buildUrl = (url) => new URL(url.pathname, url.protocol + '://' + url.host)
```

Comment: If you go through to [the types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b4b87a219c2b711fefd2f6291d6008030f273e36/types/node/url.d.ts#L158) that the warning is derived from, the deprecation tells you what to use too - the form that takes a `URL` not a vanilla object.

Comment: @user2864740  my messy search is not very effective, could you point me where that documentations is?

Comment: @jonrsharpe what is a `WHATWG URL API`?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#the-whatwg-url-api, https://url.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: To clarify [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327411/node-url-format-is-deprecated-what-should-we-use-instead?noredirect=1#comment124318315_70327411), what you've linked to in the docs is **not** the deprecated form, which is why it doesn't suggest what to use instead. https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlformaturlobject is what you're calling, https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlformaturl-options is what you should be.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks a lot, but it's still not clear for me how should I replace that `url.format(urlObject)` using the WHATWG API? Just `new URL(urlObject.pathname, urlObject.protocol + '://' + urlObject.host)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe what do you think about my answer/solution?

Comment: @jonrsharpe also curious what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node refers that the `url.format` method taking as input an `urlObject` is deprecated, although it is still a stable solution

[image]

We should now use the [WHATWG URL API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/url.html). Note that the url module fetched with `require('url')` provides two APIs for working with URLs: a legacy API that is Node.js specific, and a newer API that implements the same WHATWG URL Standard used by web browsers.

A one-liner solution that tries to emulate the legacy `url.format` method API with the new WHATWG URL Standard constructor may be

```js
const urlFrom = (urlObject) => String(Object.assign(new URL("http://a.com"), urlObject))
```

Test it here

```js
const urlFrom = (urlObject) => String(Object.assign(new URL("http://a.com"), urlObject))

const url1 = urlFrom({
  protocol: 'https',
  hostname: 'example.com',
  pathname: 'somepath'
})
console.log('url1:', url1) // https://example.com/somepath

const url2 = urlFrom({
  protocol: 'https:',
  host: 'example.com',
  pathname: '/somepath'
})
console.log('url2:', url2) // https://example.com/somepath

const url3 = urlFrom({
  protocol: 'https:',
  host: 'example.com:8080',
  pathname: '/somepath'
})
console.log('url3:', url3) // https://example.com:8080/somepath

const url4 = urlFrom({
    protocol: 'http:',
    hostname: 'example.com',
    port: 8080,
    pathname: '/somepath'
  })
console.log('url4:', url4) // http://example.com:8080/somepath

const url5 = urlFrom({
    protocol: 'https:',
    hostname: 'example.com',
    port: 8080,
    pathname: '/somepath',
    username: 'john',
    password: 'abc',
    search: 'item=bike'
  })
console.log('url5:', url5) // https://john:abc@example.com:8080/somepath?item=bike
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it doesn't support query params:/

Comment: I think this is the right solution. Query params are in the `pathname` key so it's ok. What I do not like is the `new URL(someString)` instance, but I do not find another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation for [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), and be sure to note the differences in certain properties like [`host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/host) (includes [`port`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/port)) vs [`hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hostname) (doesn't). Based on the components in your question, it seems like you need to use a function like the following, which you can extend for your needs:

```js
function urlFromComponents ({pathname = '/', protocol = 'https:', ...props} = {}) {
  const url = new URL('https://site.example');
  url.protocol = protocol;
  url.hostname = props.hostname;
  url.pathname = pathname;
  return url;
}

const protocol = 'https';
const hostname = 'example.com';
const pathname = 'somepath';

const url1 = urlFromComponents({
  hostname,
  pathname, // pathname will have "/" prepended if absent
  protocol, // protocol actually ends in ":", but this will also be fixed for you
});

const url2 = urlFromComponents({hostname, pathname});

console.log({url1, url2});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but check my answer, is more general :)